# Waiting for an ActionListener actionPerformed (with Timer?)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer, awt

I am trying to populate a variable from a JFrame and am having significant difficulties trying to get the program to wait for the action performed to occur before continuing. See code below.

JFrame implementation class:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
static String s;
static JTextField textfield;
static JButton jButton;

public void showFrame() {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    textfield = new JTextField("", 10);
    jButton = new JButton("Enter");
    jButton.addActionListener(new Frame());
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel jl = new JLabel("Options");
    jf.setSize(200, 200);
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.add(panel);
    panel.add(jl);
    panel.add(textfield);
    panel.add(jButton);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    s = textfield.getText();
}

public String reportVal(){
    return s;
}
```

}

Main Java File:

```
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    frame.showFrame();

    Timer t = new Timer(1000, frame);
    t.start();
    int trials = Integer.parseInt(frame.reportVal());
```

I want trials to populate with the value from the JFrame, but right now the thread doesn't wait, so it executes all the way through before I can click enter on the frame. I do not know much about swing/awt components (clearly) so I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: How about instead of using a `Timer` or `JFrame`, you use a modal dialog, which will block the code execution till the dialog is closed. See [How to use dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Comment: Alternately, put whatever code you want to execute after the JFrame in the `actionPerfomed` method so it triggers when the user finishes with the input.  Your code is hard to understand so you should explain better what it is you want to actually happen.